# 240v reading on a 120v outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, garage, 240v

[image][image]I just got back from visiting the house I am moving into in two weeks. I was checking out the electrical circuits in the garage to see how I will be able to run my woodworking tools. I did not get around to checking the amperage on the circuits because the simple test for live receptacles gave voltages that  threw me. There is a circuit for a Room AC with the proper outlet that reads 240 volts as it should.

The circuit over the counter over existing cabinets along one wall has two 120 v receptacles in separate boxes. When I probe the outlets I GET 240 VOLTS. There is a separate circuit with only one 120v receptacle on the back wall. It must be on a separate circuit because on it I get 40 TO 50 VOLT READINGS.  Any body have any idea about what kind of jackass wiring would cause this ?

Comment: 240V on 120V receptacles could be a sign of a big problem, or it could be a deliberate miswiring for the previous owner's tools - so either part of a big mess or possibly a really easy fix at the breaker. 40V - 50V could be phantom voltage from a partially disconnected circuit or it could be a sign of a really big problem. a) How are the circuits in the house? b) Can you upload a picture of the main panel and any subpanels?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Agreed:  the previous owner may have had a tool that needed (or converted) to 240v and didn't want to bother with changing the plug/outlet to the proper NEMA components. Dangerous and stupid, IMHO if that was the case. If the OP could pull out the outlets (WITH THE POWER OFF) as well as the cover of the main panel, take some pics, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am back at my present house but will be back to the new house tomorrow. I will get some pics and post them. However, I can tell you that the garage is on a separate sub-panel so as far as I can tell these circuits are not on the house main

Comment: Yes, pictures of all relevant panels, ideally with the deadfronts removed, would be very helpful.  Pictures looking into the outlet boxes may also be needed.

Comment: It wouldn't be a bad idea to check voltages in all the house receptacles while you're there, to see if the problem only affects the garage or exists in the house as well.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the inside of the garage subpanel and of the outlet boxes in question, once you get back to the new house of course?

Comment: Happens all the time where Goober gets a 240V appliance e.g. a big older window A/C..., does not realize the local home store sells NEMA 6 receps for that purpose, and so miswires a NEMA 5 recep. Makes a mental note not to plug anything 120V in there, changes weird A/C plug to NEMA 5, is happy.

Comment: i have added an annotated pic of the inside of the garage subpanel. First, I was disappointed to see that there is no disconnect on the sub panel so I have to use the breaker in the house main. (BTW for those concerned that the house wiring is also dodgy; it has just be completely rewired and inspected by the city complete with a new load center.)  The obvious problems I see are some grounds wired to the neutral buss bar and some neutrals wired to the ground buss bar.  The conduit headed out to the left has the two 240v receptacles that should be 120.  Further comment below

Comment: The three way pigtail between the conduit and the breaker is not right but it does not explain how I am getting 240 v  as the red is connected to the breaker, one black is going out the conduit and the second black is apparently powering the furnace fan.  What do you folks see.

Comment: The good news is the three open spaces for breakers in the panel. If the breakers for these are not out of production I can fix the double lugged breaker problems.  Plus I can eliminate the furnace fan as I am going to disconnect the old gas furnace and replace it with a new smaller unit with a thermostatically controlled fan

Comment: Where does the white wire coming out of the bench outlet pipe end up going?  It disappears behind some stuff, and then I can't track it.  Theoretically it should be on the neutral bar, but if it goes to a breaker, that explains your 240V.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the label on the inside left of the panel in question please?

Comment: Also, can you try measuring voltage at the socket for the outside lights, with the outside light switch on of course?

Comment: I traced the white wire from the bench outlet conduit. It does reemerge from behind the gray plate and is connected to the neutral buss. I am going back today and  I will try to get a pic of the label and see what voltage  get on the outside light

Comment: Picture of label posted as requested. I got into the box this morning and first checked to make sure that there was not a circuit from the house main that was feeding current into the garage wiring. I shut off the breaker feeding the garage sub-panel at the house main and checked the panel out--completely dead.  Next I cleaned up some to the mess. Got rid of the 3 wire pigtail at the plugs breaker, relocated al the grounds to the ground buss and all the neutrals to the neutral buss. Concentrated on making the bench outlet circuit and the A/C circuit right. More in next comment

Comment: Net result was that the Bench outlet circuit is now 25 volts and the A/C circuit was good at 242. So without all the cross wiring with pigtails, double lugs, grounds and neutrals at the feed wires coming from the house main the voltage reading is 25 on the left side of the sub panel and 242 on the right side. Please correct me if I am wrong but there should be 120 volts on each side, right? If so, then the wiring is screwed up at the main panel and we need to get the guy back out who wired  it, right ? BTW, I appreciate responses and help.

Comment: From each side to ground should be 120, from each side to each other should be 240

Comment: @CharlesD.Collier I see that the white wire from "to bench outlets" connects to neutral along with the aluminum ground, but if that's that case, the voltage on "to bench outlets" should be 120v.  Have you checked the voltage when there is a load (like a drill or something)?

Comment: The 25v and 40v-50v are all probably just phantom voltage from messed up grounding.

Comment: Seth, the 25volt/242 volt readings were taken after I sorted out the grounds to the neutral  bar and neutrals to the ground bar

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a loose (or open) neutral on a 3-wire circuit.  That is to say, 2 hots sharing one neutral. Going forward I am referring to these 2 hots as **A** & **B**. The 2 hots are on opposing legs of the panel, hence 240 volts.  The neutral becomes open somewhere before returning home to the main neutral bussing.

Your 240 volt problem outlet is on circuit **A**.  Somewhere on circuit **B** you have a lightbulb turned on (not illuminated due to loose neutral) that is feeding the 120 volts from **B** leg through the lightbulb and back onto the neutral.

Because this 3-wire circuit shares a neutral, AND the neutral is open prior to returning home to the neutral bussing, that neutral wire on your problem outlet is reading 120 volts to ground.  Since this 120 volts to ground is from **B** leg of the 3-wire circuit you have created the scenario you have described.